# Default results management time period for ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, default, results-window

I tend to forget that the default time period for geoprocessing results displayed in ArcMap is a meager 2 weeks, and I go back to an .mxd that I used years ago to try to refresh my memory on how I did something, and what I did back then is gone.

1. Is there a way to set the default time period for all .mxd's to "never delete" so I don't have to change for each .mxd?
2. Is there a way to view the geoprocessing history that is no longer displayed?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question

Comment: It's bad idea to keep results forever, because re-running them will cause the size of your map document to grow exponentially, till it become irresponsive. I'd say export result as script snippet and keep it in a single python script (same folder?) with name that is easy to understand. Remove all results and save mxd to keep it small and healthy. Unfortunately there are no option in Results window to export them all at once:(